# KnockoutJS ko.computed() not updating after inserting an item into an array

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following objects:

```
function Category (id, name, weight) {
    this.categoryId = ko.protectedComputed(id);
    this.name  = ko.protectedComputed(name); 
    this.weight = ko.protectedComputed(weight);
    // this.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(this);
}

function Item (id, name, categoryId, gradeMax) {
    this.itemId = ko.observable(id);
    this.name  = ko.observable(name); 
    this.categoryId = ko.observable(categoryId);
    this.gradeMax = ko.observable(gradeMax);
}

function Grade (gradeId, itemId, studentId, studentName, grade) {
    this.gradeId = gradeId;
    this.itemId =  itemId;
    this.studentId  =  studentId; 
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.grade = ko.observable(grade);
}

var viewModel =  function () {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        new Item(3, "Homework 3", 1, 10),
        new Item(1, "Homework 1", 1, 20),
        new Item(2, "Homework 2", 1, 30),
        new Item(4, "Quiz", 3, 5)
    ]);

    self.categories = ko.observableArray([ 
        new Category(1, "Homework", 50) , 
        new Category(2, "Test", 25), 
        new Category(3, "Quiz", 25)          
    ]);

    self.grades = ko.observableArray([  
        //grades for item 4
        new Grade(10, 4,1, "Olivo,  Omar", 2)  ,   
        new Grade(11, 4,2, "Mercado,  Coryann",5),           
        new Grade(12, 4,3, "Pena,  Juan", 4) 
    ]);

    self.addItem = function () {
        var randId = int.rand(); 
        var newItem = new Item(randId , "new item", 1, 100);
        self.items.push(newItem);

        self.selectedItem(newItem);           
    };

    self.getStudentAverage = function (studentId) {
        return ko.computed(function () 
        {
            var total = 0,
            numOfItems = 0;

            // Get the grades for the assignment for this student
            var studentGrades =   ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.grades(), function(grade) {                          
                return grade.studentId == studentId;
            }); 

            // Calculate the Weighted Average
            if ( self.isWeighted() == true ){
                var faceAverage= 100;

                return tempAvg ;
            }  
        }, this)();
    };
};
```

HTML

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data : $root.students, as : 'student' }  "  >                  
   <tr> 
        <td>
                <span data-bind="text: student.studentId" ></span>   - 
                <span data-bind="text: student.studentName" ></span>  
        </td>

        <td> 
             <span data-bind="text:  $root.getStudentAverage(student.studentId) "> </span> 
        </td>

        <!-- ko foreach: { data : $root.items, as : 'item' }  -->             
        <td > <!--   <span data-bind="css: { dirty : $root.getGrade(item.itemId(), student.studentId).grade.isDirty()}"></span> -->
              <input  class="grade-input" data-bind="value: $root.getGrade(item.itemId(), student.studentId).grade " />  
        </td>          
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem is that `vm.getStudentAverage()` is not updating when I insert a new item.
I'm trying to figure out why this is not working for me. I would like to compute the average for each student after inserting a new item.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pisqko/s5uGb/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Could you provide the complete implementation of your computed? In the code you provided, you aren't even referencing the items array inside the computed, so it's not going to update when items changes. Also, isWeighted() doesn't exist in your view model.

Comment: I missed the fact that you're not returning the computed. You are calling the computed immediately after creating it, so you're returning it's initial value, not the computed itself. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @wired_in for your quick replies. I created a jsfiddle with the complete js. Also, I do not reference items. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pisqko/s5uGb/)

Answer (score 2):

There are missing pieces from your code, but the main problem seems to be that you are returning the initial value of the computed observable in that function, not the computed observable itself.  So in the end, you're binding to a value and not the computed observable.

```
self.getStudentAverage = function (studentId)
{
    return ko.computed(function () 
    {
        // code...
    }, this)(); // <-- you are returning the result of the computed
};
```

Just return the computed, don't call it (with the extra `()`).

Updated code:

```
self.getStudentAverage = function (studentId)
{
    return ko.computed(function () 
    {
        // code...
    }, this);
};
```

Note: In the code you provided, you aren't even referencing the items array inside the computed. You must be using the items array for the computed to be updated when items changes. Otherwise, the computed doesn't depend on items, so there's no reason for it to update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getStudentAverage` is just a function that returns a computed observable. It has to be an observable itself. I see that you try to get it to use the studentId parameter but that would just be a workaround for an error in your design:

You need a `Student` model, then you can loop over an array of students and call something like `student.getAverage`. No need to sneak in the id anymore.

Comment: His model is fine, the getStudentAverage is just ran once to return the computed, which is fine if he wants to generate a computed in several places. As long as the computed references the items array, it should update when items changes. In his code, the computed does not reference items.